# Java Spring uploading file to FTP server

Tags: java, spring, ftp

I have the following code:

```
@Bean
    public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() throws IOException {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(ftpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("/");
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
        ftpSessionFactory().getSession().mkdir("folder");
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }
```

with this I am creating a single folder, but the thing that I want to achieve is for example given a `File`, I want upload it to that FTP server, I saw that there is a method `write()` but actually it takes two parameters and I got confused how I can do this, can you suggest please any approach, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Bean
    public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() throws IOException {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(ftpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("/");
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));

        ftpSessionFactory().getSession().mkdir("dir");
        final ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream("foo".getBytes());
        ftpSessionFactory().getSession().write(stream, "dir/myFile.txt");
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }
```

This was the answer actually, I realized that I must include ByteArray and the source where I want to write the information, I got this solution by my classmate